# Raising errors when trying to encrypt files using gpg in my ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gnupg

I've made some code to encrypt files using GPG and it works as a console application, but not on my ASP.NET MVC app. Basically, when the user clicks a button, it will download an encrypted text file like this:

```
public ActionResult ObterArquivoTodosLGPD(string Id)
{
    //Logic to create the normal file here
    string contentType = "application/vnd.ms-txt";
    EncryptFile(@"D:\VivoSimArquivos\Reset Senha Todos.txt", @"D:\VivoSimArquivos\Reset Senha Todos.txt.gpg");
    
    return File(@"D:\VivoSimArquivos\Reset Senha Todos.txt.gpg", contentType, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"D:\VivoSimArquivos\Reset Senha Todos.txt.gpg"));
}

public static void EncryptFile(string inputName, string outputName)
{
    const string commandFormat = @"--yes --batch --encrypt --output {0}  --armour --recipient {1} {2}";

    ExecuteCommandSync(string.Format(commandFormat, outputName,
                "myemailforencrpyting", inputName));
}

public static void ExecuteCommandSync(string command)
{
    // string path = string.Format(@"{0}\gpg.exe", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe");
    string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe";
    Console.WriteLine(command);

    var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, command)
            {
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin",
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true
            };

    var proc = new Process { StartInfo = procStartInfo };
    proc.Start();

    // proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(password);
    proc.StandardInput.Flush();

    // Get the output into a string
    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.WriteLine(error);
}
```

As I said before, it works as a console application, but it fails as i try to implement it in my ASP.NET MVC application.

I get this error:

> gpg: Note: '--armour' is not considered an option\r\ngpg: Note: '--recipient' is not considered an option\r\nusage: gpg [options] --encrypt [filename]\r\n"

I'm using the latest gpg4win version on my server. What could this be?

Comment: why not use a .NET library for this rather than trying to control a command-line app? There are free, ready-made .NET libraries which will do PGP encryption.

Comment: Could you recommend any? Unfortunately i only had success with command-line apps

Comment: I've used https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoPGP before with success (it mainly just provides a friendlier wrapper round the well-regarded and certified [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) libraries).

Comment: I've used the ChoPGP and it works. But whenever i try to decrypt the files it gives me this error: 'No Secret Key' (i'm using kleopatra which comes with gpg4win). Do you know what is causing this error?

Comment: I cannot read your screen, your disk, or your mind - so no I don't know what's causing it. I've no idea what files you're decrypting, what code you wrote, what key you're trying to use, or whether any of it was used correctly or not. If you need some help with it you'd have to show some relevant details as you did with your original problem. A random error message by itself is not sufficient.

Comment: Use the [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.8) Property